# Changing Bootstrap nav-link color

Tags: html, css, colors

I am trying to change my Bootstrap´s nav-link into white and I can´t. This is my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #5E9DFE;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="yellow">Div</span><span class="plate">Aid</span> <span class="salmon">T</span><span class="green">asks</span></a>
    <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        {% if session.user_id %}
             <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2" id="add-del">
                 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/add">Agregar</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/delete">Eliminar</a></li>
             </ul>
             <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2">
                 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
             </ul>
        {% else %}
             <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2" id="log-reg">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Registro</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
             </ul>
        {% endif %}
   </div>
</nav>
```

And I tried changing it, after seeing previous answers and [CSS Specificity Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp):

```
nav .navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 .nav-item .navlink{
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav .navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 .nav-item .navlink:hover{
    color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

But there´s still something missing.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: why is `.navlink` and `.navlink:hover` has same color? and also the class is `nav-link` not `navlink`.

Comment: It was wrong, I´ve edited but still is not working.

Comment: then I have posted the working code as well, you may have to tweak a code then, even after adding my code didn't work for you then, it is not with the code, some other code is overriding the CSS properties you have to do inspect element and get into the rootcause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css nesting is wrong

try this:

```
nav .navbar-nav.mr-auto.mt-2 .nav-item .nav-link{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, try adding `!Important`
to crush the predefined bootstrap styles

```
nav .navbar-nav.mr-auto.mt-2 .nav-item .nav-link{
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment there is no class called `.navlink` in the snippet.

Comment: Great! It works, I was missing the `!important` part. Thanks, Bru17 and Manjuboyz for your help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.nav-link {
  color: red;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #5E9DFE;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="yellow">Div</span><span class="plate">Aid</span> <span class="salmon">T</span><span class="green">asks</span></a>
  <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    {% if session.user_id %}
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2" id="add-del">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/add">Agregar</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/delete">Eliminar</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2" id="log-reg">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/register">Registro</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the CSS from the nav-link class to white

```
.nav-link {color: white;}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bruno, I´ve tried this code but finally, the `!important` statement crushed the predefined bootstrap styles and made it work.